# JSON path extractor to count the no of keys

Tags: regex, json, performance, jmeter

I am having sample json

```
[
:   {
:   :   "id":"255",
:   :   "name”:”abc”,
:   },
:   {
:   :   "id":"257",
:   :   "name”:”xyz”,
:   }
]
```

I am using json path extractor in jmeter to get the values of id and name.
However is it possible to get the count of ids or names in a straight forward way.
I know if I use regex extractor and using for loop to get the count.

Answer (score 2):

Use regular expression extractor and set no. of match to a negative no. then reference name_matchNr variable should give you the count of occurances of string.

like,

[image]

Then expression_matchNr variable should give you the count of id occurances.

For additional reference see JMeter help,[Regular Expression extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)

Comment: Thanks . however I've mentioned that in my question as well that I can use regex etractor. But I am looking if is it possible through json path extractor?

Comment: Yes, I think you only need count, If you json path extractor there is no straightforward way to get it. You need to extract all values then count the occuarances and then store it in some variable and then use it. Whats the point in not using available functionality.

Comment: I've found that using Regexs to extract JSON can be more trouble than it's worth, particularly when the data you're looking for is buried a few layers in and/or you have similarly named structures.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible via some scripting.

For example, if you have the following JSON payload:

```
{"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}
```

And the following JSONPath Expression:

```
$.employees..firstName
```

which returns first names as follows:

```
["John","Anna","Peter"]
```

You can get matches number by counting commas in the resulting variable.

Given that you're using "name" as the Variable Name in JSON Path Extractor

1. Add the a [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) below JSONPath extractor
2. Put the following code into the PostProcessor's "Script" area:

   ```
   int matches = vars.get("name").split(",").length;
   vars.put("matches",String.valueOf(matches));
   ```
3. Optionally add a [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and a [View Results Tree Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) and run your test

You should have "matches" variable containing "3"

For more information on Beanshell scripting in Apache JMeter see [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide.

Comment: Thanks. It would be better if JSON extractor gives some in-built method to do this so we don't need the debug sampler

Comment: You can suggest this at [JMeter Plugins Support Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jmeter-plugins/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it using Json Extractor as well. For your given Json you can add a Json Extractor in your HTTP Sampler and a Debug Sampler(to see result) next to you HTTP sampler as shown below
[image]

and set variable and path expression as follow
[image]

See response data of debug sampler and you will get result at last

idCount_matchNr=2